# Replace a single character in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I am using Linux Libertine as my font in my thesis and I love every character except for the italic uppercase J. However, the uppercase J in mathmode is nice and I would like to replace the italic J with the mathmode J. Is this possible? MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
    
I do not like the italic \textit{J}, I want $J$ for that.
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[MWE compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kazE.png)

I know that mathmode J is produced by the `newtxmath` package, whereas the italic J is provided by the `libertine` package itself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question might be more suited for the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com). I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234767), which appears to be similar to what you are trying to achieve.